# System.Diagnostics.Process.Start consistently fails the second time

Tags: c#

I have the following code that opens documents from my application:

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fileName);`

This has been working fine for years, and it works fine on other people's computers as well.

However, I recently got a new computer. On my computer, it works only once: I click the button, and the document opens. When I try to do the exact same thing a second time, I get this error:

```
Message: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The specified procedure could not be found
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(String fileName)
   at Citadel.Products.Entity.ProductFactSheetDetail.DownLoad(String path, Boolean includeDateInFileName, Boolean addGuidToFileName, Boolean fileNameKeepSpaces, Boolean viewDocument)
   at Citadel.Products.Entity.ProductFactSheetDetail.DownLoad(Boolean includeDateInFileName)
   at Citadel.Products.Interface.Controls.FactSheetVersionSelectorControl.btnView_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Dev\Src\Tyrus\CodeBase\Development\Citadel.Products\Citadel.Products.Interface\Controls\FactSheetVersionSelectorControl.cs:line 81 - The specified procedure could not be found
Stack Trace:    at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(String fileName)
   at Citadel.Products.Entity.ProductFactSheetDetail.DownLoad(String path, Boolean includeDateInFileName, Boolean addGuidToFileName, Boolean fileNameKeepSpaces, Boolean viewDocument)
   at Citadel.Products.Entity.ProductFactSheetDetail.DownLoad(Boolean includeDateInFileName)
   at Citadel.Products.Interface.Controls.FactSheetVersionSelectorControl.btnView_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Dev\Src\Tyrus\CodeBase\Development\Citadel.Products\Citadel.Products.Interface\Controls\FactSheetVersionSelectorControl.cs:line 81
Application: Citadel.Tyrus
Version: 1.0.0.0
OSVersion: Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
Description:
```

The only way to get rid of this error, is to restart my application.

Clearly this is not a coding issue, something is not right on my computer, but I have no idea where to start looking. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: The error cannot be related to the file being opened. Whenever we download a file from the database, we always add a random Guid to the file name to ensure it is unique.

EDIT: The problem seems to only occur with MS Office documents. When I open a PDF document or a bmp, the error does not occur.

Comment: Most likely your file is locked and therefore it can not be opened the next time. Check in the task manager if the process is still running.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, unfortunately, that cannot be the explanation: Every time I download a file through the system, we add a Guid to the file name to ensure it is unique

Comment: I'm almost certain that this will turn out to be a COM registration issue with whatever application is registered to handle these files. A repair on that application may fix things up.

Comment: "The specified procedure could not be found" is a very specific error, it is very selective to having a problem with a DLL.  Only getting it the second time is however very unusual, maybe you shouldn't focus on that too much.  Google "windows enable loader snaps" to find out how to get better diagnostics for this mishap.  Specific to C# you'll have to enable unmanaged debugging to see the diagnostic messages in the Output window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've finally fixed the problem by reinstalling the dot Net Framework. (Warning, though: Doing this is not for the faint hearted. (I am faint hearted) If you think it's a simple matter of uninstalling and reinstalling, think again)

Answer (score 0):

[Win32Exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca(v=vs.110).aspx) 
There was an error in opening the associated file.

I think your file (like Excel) can't be opened twice.

Check if the file is already opened before opening it

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, unfortunately, that cannot be the explanation: Every time I download a file through the system, we add a Guid to the file name to ensure it is unique.